# How to convert a text keys into hex in Django and viceversa?

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-forms, django-views

I am trying to save a long text in hex format in Django database. 
This are some secret keys.
Also at some point I want to convert them to text again.

```
def import_keys(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        secrets = request.POST['text_file']


        some = secrets.encode("hex")       
        Keys.objects.create(hexa=some)
```

Comment: show error message (in question).

Comment: you might as well use `base64` to change text to `base64` - it will **NOT SAFE** too :) `base64.b64encode("Hello World".encode('utf-8'))`

Comment: If they are secret keys why don't you use hash value ?

Answer (score 0):

to encode::

```
text = "hello"

text.encode("hex")
```

to decode::

```
hexcode = <hex value>

hexcode.decode("hex")
```

I hope this helps.
:)